# Проблема с файлом

Tags: webpack

При запуске webpack он создает из одной фотографии -> 2 файла png и подключает второй файл, который не отображает фотографию, а первый файл нормальный, но он его не использует

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            },
```

фото задано через css

```
.logo {
    background-image: url("../assets/webpack-logo.png");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
    type: 'asset/resource',
},
```

Вместо:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
    use: ['file-loader'],
},
```